# Are these grammars left recursive and why?

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, left-recursion

I've got these grammars to solve the left recursion. But why are these grammars left recursive? They are not following the schema `A -> Aa | b`:

1., `S → 0S1 | 01`

2., `S → + SS | * SS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these grammars left recursive

No.

> and why?

In both cases you can never reach `S` (which is the only non-terminal) without consuming a terminal first. In the first grammar the only occurrence of `S` is preceded by the terminal `0` and in the second each occurrence is either preceded by `+` or `*`.

Comment: Thank you @sepp2k !